# gVim - Use different fonts using :highlight

Tags: syntax-highlighting, gvim, font

I want to set gVim font size for `Comment` highlight group. When I set it, it does not do anything (the font is still the same but color changes).

My `.gvimrc`:

```
se guifont=Fira\ Mono\ Regular\ 10
hi Comment guibg=#ff0000 font='Liberation Mono Regular 10'
```