# How to use different font size for different highlight group?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, gvim, font

There is a similar question [gVim - Use different fonts using :highlight](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18660/gvim-use-different-fonts-using-highlight) but no answer yet.

In short, is it possible to apply different font size to different highlight group?

For example, while normal font size is 10, is it possible to set the Comment group font size at 8, and Title group as 12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible.

The all Vim philosophy is based on fix width font and that is not compatible with variable font size (or non fix width font either)